# Need deleted data from locked phone

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

My moto g phone 5.1 pattern is locked accidently, is there any way to get my images from phone.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is unlocked, you can try using 'Recuva' software for recovering data from a deleted or formatted phone.
Although the Success of Recovery is not 100% and every file may not be recovered, but you can still recover most of the data which is lost (accidentally or purposely :p )